# Number of points on a hyperbolic sphere a certian distance apart

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, entropy

Let $\mathbb{H}$ denote the upper half-plane with hyperbolic metric. Choose $p \in \mathbb{H}$. Let $\delta:=\lim\limits_{R\to \infty}\frac{\log(Vol\left(B(p,R)\right))}{R}$ be the volume entropy. This is independent of base point and a calculation shows $\delta=1$.

**Question:** Is it true that there exists a positive constant $c$ having the property:

For any $2<R, 0<r<1 $, one can find $k > c\frac{\exp(\delta R)}{r}$ points $p_1,\dots,p_k$ with $d(p_i,p)=R$ and $d(p_i,p_j)>2r$?

All I see is that $\exp(\delta R)$ will tend to $Vol(B(p,R))$ as $R$ tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upper half-plane model is not relevant here -- this is a problem about the hyperbolic plane, you do not use the specific model in the statement, and I do not think it provides any insight about how to solve the problem. (I would use the Minkowski hyperboloid model myself.)

So you have a circle of radius $R$ and want to fit points in distance $2r$. An almost solution is to note that a hyperbolic circle of radius $R$ has length $2\pi \sinh(R)$, so you would fit $\frac{2\pi \sinh(R)}{2r} = \Theta(e^R/r)$ points on it.

The catch is that this measures distances along the circle -- but if the distance along the circle is $2r$, the actual distance between two points, i.e., the chord, will be shorter (they will be almost the same if $r$ is small, but the ratio is larger when $r$ is large and $R$ is small). So you would have to show that the ratio of distance along the circle to the chord is bounded by a constant when $2<R, 0<r<1$. I have not computed this, but it should be easy to do e.g. by using the hyperbolic version of the cosine theorem to compute the angle (as seen from $p$) between two points with distance $d$ along the chord.

Comment: So my question actually has nothing to do with entropy?

Comment: Well, the problem can be solved with basic hyperbolic geometry. I do not know anything about volume entropy (except the definition and a quick Wikipedia read), maybe it can be used to solve the problem too. Of course the fact that volumes and perimeters of hyperbolic balls are exponential is essential.

Comment: I *think* the calculations you suggested would fail if $\delta$ was different from $1$. So perhaps the statement in general is false on replacing $\delta$ with some other constant. This statement was actually posed for hyperbolic spaces of any dimension.